I need to automatically attach authorization tokens to requests in Laravel
I need to create a middleware in Laravel that automatically attaches an Authorization header to requests in Laravel. The purpose is to allow non-authenticated users to access authenticated routes.
through a guest account. Below, I've included what I was able to come up with:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AutoAssignGuestToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();
        $guestToken = '';

        if (! $bearerToken) {
            $guestToken = $this->createGuestToken($request);
        }

        $tokenId = substr($bearerToken, 0, 1);
        $token = substr($bearerToken, 1);

        $idExists = \DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
            ->where('id', $tokenId)
            ->exists();

        $tokenExists = \DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
            ->where('token', $token)
            ->exists();

        if (! $idExists || ! $tokenExists) {
            $guestToken = $this->createGuestToken($request);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        if ($guestToken) {
            return $response->withCookie(cookie('guest_token', $guestToken, 60 * 24 * 7)); // Expires in 7 days
        }

        return $response;
    }

    protected function createGuestToken(Request $request): string
    {
        $randomNumbers = rand(pow(10, 5 - 1), pow(10, 5) - 1);
        $guest = User::create([
            'name' => "Guest{$randomNumbers}",
        ]);
        Auth::loginUsingId($guest->id);
        $plainTextToken = $request->user()->createToken('Bearer')->plainTextToken;

        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $plainTextToken);

        return $plainTextToken;
    }
}

The approach I came up with doesn't actually work, my routes also include the auth middleware and it just tries to redirect me to the login route.
UPDATE #1:
I updated the code to include proper validation of the token. It's probably not the best approach, but it's an approach.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AutoAssignGuestToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();

        if (! $this->isValidBearerToken($bearerToken)) {
            $bearerToken = $this->createGuestToken($request);
        }

        $response = $next($request);

        $this->addTokenToPayload($response, $bearerToken);

        return $response;
    }

    protected function createGuestToken(Request $request): string
    {
        $randomNumbers = rand(pow(10, 5 - 1), pow(10, 5) - 1);
        $guest = User::create([
            'name' => "Guest{$randomNumbers}",
        ]);
        Auth::guard('web')->loginUsingId($guest->id);
        $plainTextToken = $request->user()->createToken('Bearer')->plainTextToken;

        $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $plainTextToken);

        return $plainTextToken;
    }

    protected function isValidBearerToken($bearerToken): bool
    {
        if (!$bearerToken) {
            return false;
        }

        $tokenArr = explode('|', $bearerToken, 2);
        if (count($tokenArr) !== 2) {
            return false;
        }

        $idQuery = \DB::table('personal_access_tokens')
            ->where('id', $tokenArr[0]);

        if (! $idQuery->exists()) {
            return false;
        }

        $retrievedToken = $idQuery->first()?->token;

        return $retrievedToken === hash('sha256', $tokenArr[1]);
    }

    protected function addTokenToPayload(Response $response, string $bearerToken): void
    {
        // The response content is in the form of stringified json so it needs to be decoded
        $responseContentDecoded = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        // A token key is placed inside the data token
        $responseContentDecoded['data']['token'] = $bearerToken;

        $response->setContent(json_encode($responseContentDecoded));
    }
}


INFO: I want to use this middleware as the sole middleware for my API route. The purpose is to assign tokens to certain routes that exist prior to the one's where authentication is absolutely necessary.
